# how to align text and image in a card view

Tags: ios, view, card

how to align the texts and image inside a card view like the image given .can anyone please help me[this is the sample image, I want the view like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26mHj.png)

```
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20,style: .circular)
            .fill(.white)
            .border(.gray,width: 1)
        VStack(spacing: 5){
            HStack(spacing: 20){
                Image("heart")
                    .frame(alignment: .topTrailing)
            }
            Text(productData.title)
                .font(.headline)
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Text("\(productData.price,specifier: "%.2f")/1Kg")
                .font(.subheadline)
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            }
       
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
        .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
    }
    .frame(width: 350,height: 250)
          
    }
```

}